# Excel: how to count combinations that go both ways

Tags: excel, count, combinations

I need your help with Excel because I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

So let's say I have column A and column B and in each column there are different colors. I've already created pivot table to count how many times a certain combination occurs, however, I don't know how to count the same combination of colors that occur in the reverse order as one. For examble combination 1 is red-green and combination 2 is green-red. Pivot table counts these as different entitites.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The problem is that I have 736 different combinations. With the above formula it would take me ages to look for duplicate calculated numbers. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: I would just put each pair of items into alphabetical order, so red-green would become green-red

Comment: Yes in the end I did that and though it took some time, it is now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions

(1) Keep it simple

Just set up a helper column containing each pair in alphabetical order

```
=IF(A2<B2,A2&"-"&B2,B2&"-"&A2)
```

then run a pivot table on the result.

(2) Make it complicated

List the different pairs using a formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10&"-"&B$2:B$10,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF(G$1:G1,A$2:A$10&"-"&B$2:B$10)=0)*(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,B$2:B$10&"-"&A$2:A$10)=0)*(A$2:A$10&B$2:B$10<>""),0),0)),"")
```

Then count them

```
=IF(G2="","",SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(G2,A$2:A$10&"-"&B$2:B$10)+COUNTIF(G2,B$2:B$10&"-"&A$2:A$10)))
```

The second way has the advantage that it is dynamic and doesn't need helper columns.

The first way is faster and puts the results in alphabetical order.

[image]